# intermittent "java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement is closed."

Tags: java, tomcat

I had been facing this exception from very long time. 
My tomcat/java web application having very large no of database transaction. 
I am using MSSQL server as my back end and using DBCP, database connection pooling in tomcat.
I have following practice of using this.

DB pooling in my servlet.

```
//Skeleton
dopost
{
  //geting connection using JNDI
  //Creating statement object
  // calling method of execution of Business Logic 
}
finally
{
  //closing all DB resorces
}
Business Logic
{
  //do all Database transaction
}

//Original code spinet
public class Frm_mst_operation_II extends HttpServlet
{

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpservletrequest, HttpServletResponse httpservletresponse) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    try
    {
        String option=httpservletrequest.getParameter("option");            
        InitialContext initialcontext = new InitialContext();
        if(initialcontext == null)
            throw new Exception("Boom - No Context");

        InitialContext initialcontext2 = new InitialContext();
        if(initialcontext2 == null)
            throw new Exception("Boom - No Context");
        Context context = (Context)initialcontext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        Context context2 = (Context)initialcontext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        DataSource datasource = (DataSource)context.lookup(RuntimeConf.abi_database);
        DataSource datasource_sql = (DataSource)context2.lookup(RuntimeConf.abi_sql_database);
        if(datasource != null)
        {
            if(dbcon == null)
            {
                dbcon = datasource.getConnection();
            }
            else
            {
                if(!dbcon.isClosed())
                {
                    dbcon.close();
                }
                dbcon = datasource.getConnection();
            }

            if(dbcon_sql == null)
            {
                dbcon_sql = datasource_sql.getConnection();
            }
            else
            {
                if(!dbcon_sql.isClosed())
                {
                    dbcon_sql.close();
                }
                dbcon_sql = datasource_sql.getConnection();
            }

            if(dbcon_sql != null)
            {
                dbcon.setAutoCommit(false);
                dbcon_sql.setAutoCommit(false);
                stmt_ora1 = dbcon.createStatement();
                stmt = dbcon_sql.createStatement();

                if(option.equals("Insert_cge_Data"))
                { 
                    Insert_CGE_Data(httpservletrequest);                
                }

                dbcon.close();
                dbcon_sql.close();
                dbcon=null;
                dbcon_sql=null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Data Source Not Found - Error : Exception In Frm_mst_operation_II");
        }

        httpservletresponse.sendRedirect(url);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception In Frm_mst_operation_II And Exception Is :: "+exception);
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(rset != null) 
        { 
            try 
            {
                rset.close(); 
            }
            catch(SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Frm_mst_operation_II "+e);
            }
            rset = null;
        }
        if(stmt != null) 
        {    
            try
            {
                stmt.close(); 
            }
            catch(SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Frm_mst_operation_II "+e);
            }
            stmt = null;
        }
        if(stmt_ora1 != null) 
        {    
            try
            {
                stmt_ora1.close(); 
            }
            catch(SQLException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Frm_mst_operation_II "+e);
            }
            stmt_ora1 = null;
        }
        if(dbcon != null) 
        { 
            try
            {
                dbcon.close(); 
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Frm_mst_operation_II "+e);
            }
            dbcon = null;

        }
        if(dbcon_sql != null) 
        { 
            try
            {
                dbcon_sql.close(); 
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception in Frm_mst_operation_II "+e);
            }
            dbcon_sql = null;

        }
    }
}//End Of doPost() Method ...

public void Insert_CGE_Data(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException,
ServletException, SQLException {

    try 
    {

        query_th_ora = "  INSERT INTO PR_OPR_TH " + " ( "
        + " COMP_N, YR_N, TRN_N, TRN_C, "
        + " TRN_D, MCH_N, SHIFT_N, STRT_TIME, "
        + " END_TIME,  PROD_N, BODY_N, "
        + " CAR_N , FIRE_N, CREATED_UID," + " CREATED_D , " +
        // " UPDATED_UID, UPDATED_D" +
        " TRNTYP , TOT_QTY " + " , RSN_N ) " + " VALUES " + " ( "
        + " '" + comp_cd + "', '" + yr_n + "', '" + TRN_N
        + "', 'CGE" + TRN_C + "', " + " to_date('" + trn_d
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy') , '" + mch_nm
        + "', '" + shift + "', to_date('" + in_time
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), " + " to_date('"
        + out_time + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), '" + prod_n
        + "', '" + body_n + "', " + " '" + car_n + "', '"
        + fire_n + "',  '" + user_cd + "',to_date('"+ora_sysdt+"', 'dd/mm/yyyy  HH24:MI:SS'), " + " 'CGE', '" + tot_qty + "'"
        + " , '"+RSN_N+"' ) " + " ";

        //SQL MD20230302

        query_th_sql = "  INSERT INTO PROD.PR_OPR_TH " + " ( "
        + " COMP_N, YR_N, TRN_N, TRN_C, "
        + " TRN_D, MCH_N, SHIFT_N, STRT_TIME, "
        + " END_TIME,  PROD_N, BODY_N, "
        + " CAR_N , FIRE_N, CREATED_UID," + " CREATED_D , " +
        // " UPDATED_UID, UPDATED_D" +
        " TRNTYP , TOT_QTY " + " , RSN_N, FLAG) " + " VALUES " + " ( "
        + " '" + comp_cd + "', '" + yr_n + "', '" + TRN_N
        + "', 'CGE" + TRN_C + "', " + " PROD.to_date('" + trn_d
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy') , '" + mch_nm
        + "', '" + shift + "', PROD.to_date('" + in_time
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), " + " PROD.to_date('"
        + out_time + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), '" + prod_n
        + "', '" + body_n + "', " + " '" + car_n + "', '"
        + fire_n + "',  '" + user_cd + "', PROD.to_date('" + sysdt
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), " + " 'CGE', '" + tot_qty + "'"
        + " , '"+RSN_N_SQL+"', 'Y'  ) " ;



        //ORA
        query_td_ora = "INSERT INTO PR_OPR_TD" + " ("
        + " COMP_N, YR_N,  TRN_N, TRN_C,  "
        + " TRN_D, TRNDTL_N, SRNO_C, QTY, SMPL_RMK,  "
        + " OPR_N, OPRGRP_N, NXT_OPR,  REJTYP_N,  "
        + " REJ_QTY,  STATUS,  SRNO_N,  DECK_NO,  "
        + " CREATED_UID , CREATED_D , " +
        " TRNTYP, PREV_OPR, GOOD_QTY, PREV_STATUS,  "
        + " BODY_N, BARCODE_NO, PREVTRNDTL_N, PROD_N, " + "" +
        " glzsrno_c, good_wt, exttrn_d," +
        " glztrn_d, unit_wt, layer_n, zones_n, SOTTRN_D, ASSBLD_STS" +
        " )" + " VALUES"
        + "(" + " '" + comp_cd + "', '" + yr_n + "', '" + TRN_N
        + "', 'CGE" + TRN_C + "', " + " to_date('" + trn_d
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '" + trndtl_n + "',  '" + srno_c + "', '" + accept_qty
        + "',  '" + barcode_no + "', " + " '" + OPR_N + "', '"
        + OPRGRP_N + "', '" + NXT_OPR + "', '" + REJTYP_N + "',  "
        + " '" + rej_qty + "', '" + status + "', '" + srno_n
        + "', '" + deck_no + "', " + " '" + user_cd
        + "',  to_date('"+ora_sysdt+"', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'), "
        + " 'CGE', '" + opr_n + "', '" + good_qty + "', '"
        + PREV_STATUS + "',  " + " '" + body_n + "', '"
        + barcode_no + "', '" + TRNDTL_N + "'" + " , '"+prod_n+"', " +
        " '" + glzsrno_c + "', '" + good_wt + "', to_date('" + exttrn_d + "' , 'dd/mm/yyyy'), " +
        " to_date('" + glztrn_d + "' , 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '" + unit_wt + "', '" + layer_n + "', " +
        " '" + zones_n + "', to_date('"+SOTTRN_D+"', 'dd/mm/yyyy'),'"+ASSBLD_STS+"' " +
        ")";
        //SQL MD20230302
        query_td_sql = "INSERT INTO PROD.PR_OPR_TD" + " ("
        + " COMP_N, YR_N,  TRN_N, TRN_C,  "
        + " TRN_D, TRNDTL_N, SRNO_C, QTY, SMPL_RMK,  "
        + " OPR_N, OPRGRP_N, NXT_OPR,  REJTYP_N,  "
        + " REJ_QTY,  STATUS,  SRNO_N,  DECK_NO,  "
        + " CREATED_UID , CREATED_D , " +
        " TRNTYP, PREV_OPR, GOOD_QTY, PREV_STATUS,  "
        + " BODY_N, BARCODE_NO, PREVTRNDTL_N, PROD_N, " + "" +
        " glzsrno_c, good_wt, exttrn_d," +
        " glztrn_d, unit_wt, layer_n, zones_n, FLAG, SOTTRN_D, ASSBLD_STS" +
        " )" + " VALUES"
        + "(" + " '" + comp_cd + "', '" + yr_n + "', '" + TRN_N
        + "', 'CGE" + TRN_C + "', " + " PROD.to_date('" + trn_d
        + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '" + trndtl_n + "',  '" + srno_c + "', '" + accept_qty
        + "',  '" + barcode_no + "', " + " '" + OPR_N + "', '"
        + OPRGRP_N + "', '" + NXT_OPR + "', '" + REJTYP_N_SQL + "',  "
        + " '" + rej_qty + "', '" + status + "', '" + srno_n
        + "', '" + deck_no + "', " + " '" + user_cd
        + "', PROD.to_date('" + sysdt + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), "
        + " 'CGE', '" + opr_n + "', '" + good_qty + "', '"
        + PREV_STATUS + "',  " + " '" + body_n + "', '"
        + barcode_no + "', '" + TRNDTL_N + "'" + " , '"+prod_n+"', " +
        " '" + glzsrno_c + "', '" + good_wt + "', PROD.to_date('" + exttrn_d + "' , 'dd/mm/yyyy'), " +
        " PROD.to_date('" + glztrn_d + "' , 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '" + unit_wt + "', '" + layer_n + "', " +
        " '" + zones_n + "', 'Y', PROD.to_date('"+SOTTRN_D+"', 'dd/mm/yyyy'), '"+ASSBLD_STS+"' " 
        +")";

        //System.out.println(query_th_ora);
        stmt_ora1.executeUpdate(query_th_ora);
        //System.out.println(query_th_sql);
        stmt3.executeUpdate(query_th_sql);

        //System.out.println(query_td_ora);
        stmt_ora1.executeUpdate(query_td_ora);
        //System.out.println(query_td_sql);
        stmt3.executeUpdate(query_td_sql);

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        dbcon.rollback(); 
        dbcon_sql.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        dbcon.rollback(); 
        dbcon_sql.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}
And some where in between Business Logic method I always got that exception. 
And strange thing is that I always got this exception in my servlets only never in Databean. 
I know the why this exception is raise but I don't understand the cause. 
 
And second thing My tomcat service get also hang intermittently. 
 
become completely unresponsive, need to restr in order to run the application again.

So request to all of u to please respond my query/que/issue and help me to get out of this mud bag. One thing to mention is my client machines runs on WiFi network, does it has any effect on the raising this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can get this exception when try to use the `PreparedStatemen` while its close
This id detailed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184312/org-apache-commons-dbcp-delegatingpreparedstatement-is-closed)

Comment: First of all @CRDave Thanks a lot for formatting my post, i m new so don't knw how to post at all.

Comment: Second @TEckExchange i am not using any prepared Statement in my application, not at all. So is there any other solution to that.

Comment: in that case revealing bit more of your source might help

Comment: I am editing my original question and adding some original code of mine, please have look at it

Comment: Hello all please help me to sort out this problem of mine. I got this hanging problem of my tomcat service, which is intermittent in nature. I m using Mricrosoft Server 2008  with 6gb of RAM. the tomcat is hosting only one application, the application had around 20 user logged in at same time with very large no of DB transaction which are executed in every 5 sec.